# Regarding Routing in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a url like www.abc.com in mvc3 application, i set a default map.route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
   new { controller = "UserLogOnPage", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

now what is happening when i type www.abc.com and enter it goes to  Controller:UserLogOnPage Method:Logon and in browser url is also showing  www.abc.com which is correct,  but when enter url like www.abc.com/UserLogOnPage/Logon same method and controller ,i want url like www.abc.com not www.abc.com/UserLogOnPage/Logon how can i do this.

Thanks

Comment: You would require url mapping to redirect the www.abc.com/UserLogOnPage/Logon to www.abc.com in your global.asax

Answer (score 1):

I am almost certain this isn't what you are actually trying to do - that route configuration will result in *any* URL being redirected to the `LogOn` page.

Going by the url what it *looks* you are after is actually authentication i.e. if an anonymous user visits `www.abc.com` they are asked to log on before they can get access to the site.

Luckily for you, MVC has already done the hardwork all you need to do is decide how you want it to work. Authentication can be applied at various levels and the scope is determined by where via the [AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) is set.

**Global.asax** - authentication required by every action

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    ...
    filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

**Controller** - authentication required for all actions within a particular controller

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

**Action** - authentication required for this action only

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AccountDetails()
{
    ...
}
```

To determine which page you want users to be redirected to as a result of the `AuthorizeAttribute`, you can configure the `authorization` section in the `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/UserLogOnPage/LogOn" />
</authentication>
```